# Symfony doctrine YAML mapping lifecycleCallbacks:prePersist

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, yaml

So I am new to doctrine YAML mapping and I was unsure on something. Basically I have the following YAML file which I have stripped down for you and also the generated Entity file.

**YAML:**

```
# src/ACME/Base/UserBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/User.orm.yml
ACME\UserBundle\Entity\User:
    table: fos_user
    type:  entity
    repositoryClass: ACME\UserBundle\Repository\User
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            generator:
                strategy: AUTO
    fields:
        firstName:
            type: string
            length: 30
            column: first_name
            nullable: false
        lastName:
            type: string
            length: 50
            column: last_name
            nullable: false
        dateJoined:
            type: datetime
            column: date_joined
            nullable: false
```

**ENTITY:**

```
<?php

namespace ACME\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * User
 */
class User
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $firstName;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $lastName;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     */
    private $dateJoined;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set firstName
     *
     * @param string $firstName
     * @return User
     */
    public function setFirstName($firstName)
    {
        $this->firstName = $firstName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get firstName
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getFirstName()
    {
        return $this->firstName;
    }

    /**
     * Set lastName
     *
     * @param string $lastName
     * @return User
     */
    public function setLastName($lastName)
    {
        $this->lastName = $lastName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get lastName
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getLastName()
    {
        return $this->lastName;
    }

    /**
     * Set dateJoined
     *
     * @param \DateTime $dateJoined
     * @return User
     */
    public function setDateJoined($dateJoined)
    {
        $this->dateJoined = $dateJoined;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get dateJoined
     *
     * @return \DateTime 
     */
    public function getDateJoined()
    {
        return $this->dateJoined;
    }
}
```

So my question is I can add the following so set the dateJoined before it saves:

```
lifecycleCallbacks:
        prePersist: [ setDateJoinedInsert ]
```

However my issue is that because I have created the column I also generate a mutator (setter) which means someone could then override the dateJoined value which I don't want to do. So is there a way not to generate a mutator automatically or do I have to then remove it from the entity file ? the issue I have is that if someone makes a change to the YAML file and re-generates the entity file the mutator will then be created again.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own override in the setter, so it can never be set.

```
public function setDateJoined($dateJoined)
{
    $this->dateJoined = new \DateTime('now');

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: but then someone could still access that setter, I want it so that the value is only ever set once.

Comment: @OliverBS inside the setter do the check `if ($this->dateJoined != null)` ?

Comment: but I could still pass it something, I could pass it today's date. I know it won't use that date but I don't want the date overriding and I want to know if there is a way in the doctrine YAML mapper to tell it not to use a setter

Comment: @OliverBS maybe create a new setter especially for the PrePersist callback?

Comment: that is my only option really, create the new setter for PrePersist and delete the old one but it is a manual process and my issue is that if someone re-runs the mapper I will loose it

Comment: @OliverBS I'm sorry, no other ideas come to mind. I'm curious for other answers, good luck :)

Comment: On a side note the PrePersist method inside the entity is auto generated

Answer (score 0):

Like user3442077 said if you check the value of your field you will be able to set it only once.
If the object is hydrated with a value then, the setter won't do anything, even if you call it with a value.